# Getting INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR: DOM Exception 5

Tags: javascript, dom, domexception

I'm writing a simple to-do list. that a user input a text and the it's added as a `checkbox`. But i'm getting this error i have no idea what's it about

> ```
> INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR: DOM Exception 5
> ```

```
window.onload = function(){
    var textBox = document.getElementById("taskInput"),
        submitBtn = document.getElementById("submit"),
        taskPool = document.getElementById("todoTask");

    submitBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){
        var task = document.createElement("<input type=\"checkbox\">" + textBox.value + "</input>");
        taskPool.appendChild(task);
    });

}
```

Comment: `createElement` expects a string containing a tag name, not HTML. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createElement

Comment: IE8 and below allowed arbitrary HTML string in `createElement`, e.g. `document.createElement('<input name="xyz">')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[document.createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createElement) takes the tag name only as its parameter, you'll have to set the type and value after

```
var task = document.createElement("input")
task.type = "checkbox";
task.value = textBox.value;
```

Also input tags are empty, there are no closing tag or inner html, the value is set as an attribute in markup.

Comment: ah, that worked. But how can i add a label inside each box ? because a checkbox without text appears when i press the button.

Comment: @Rafael you don't put labels inside cheeckboxes you put it next to them and use the label's `for` attribute to specify which checkbox the label is for.

Comment: @Rafael The property for the `for` attribute is `htmlFor` see `http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/6gbSE/4/`

Comment: Ya, i just figured it out. Thanks a lot :)