# Passing non-string attributes to a $compile function

Tags: dom, angularjs

I made an html-renderer directive which accepts a string and turns it into html elements:

```
.directive('htmlRenderer', function($compile) {
  var linker = function(scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.$watch('template', function() {
      element.html(scope.template);
      $compile(element.contents())(scope);
      console.log("Template", scope.template);
    });
  };

  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    link: linker,
    scope: {
      template: '@'
    }
  };
});
```

My problem is that I get a 'DOM Exception 5' when passing objects as attributes:

`<html-rendered template='<foo x-data={{ neededData }}/>'/>`

And in my controller I have:

```
function Controller($scope) {
  $scope.neededData = { text: 'Foo needs this for something' };
}
```

Here's a fiddle of it: http://jsfiddle.net/9U7CJ/2/

I've come across this question: [Getting INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR: DOM Exception 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11704320/getting-invalid-character-err-dom-exception-5)
which pretty much means I'm doing something wrong. And sadly, I don't know much about DOM soo I'm pretty much stuck.

I've read and re-read the Angular Docs for $compile and about the link/compile functions but it didn't get any clearer for me. Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: may be try to jsonize it first : `$scope.neededData = angular.toJson({text: 'Foo .... })` ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11819301/how-to-use-angular-tojson-on-a-angular-controller-or-scope

Comment: you are aware there is ngBindTemplate, right ? http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngBindTemplate. 
BTW, you have too many singles quotes, hence your error

Comment: can you post Plunker or Fiddle?

Comment: @Cherniv - but it's already JSON, unless there's some behind-the-scenes magic that is happening that I don't know of

Comment: @Utopik - yea I saw that in the angular docs but really couldn't comprehend how/when to use it. (My Angular knowledge is around 4~ on a scale of 1-10). Yea, updated the code :)

Comment: @MaximShoustin - added a fiddle :)